# Manual broadcasting for numpy in boolean expressions?

Tags: numpy, broadcast

Why can't numpy broadcast the following expression?

```
moves[rf_current> rf_max] = np.nan
```

The shapes are as follows:

```
moves.shape = (5,4)
rf_max.shape = (5,1)
rf_current.shape = (5,1)
```

Is it correct that I have to manually broadcast `rf_current` to make it work, or is there a better way?

Currently it gives the error:

```
IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 1; dimension is 4 but corresponding boolean dimension is 1
```

It can be easily fixed by replacing rf_current with `rf_current = np.broadcast_to(rf_current, moves.shape)`. But I have a feeling this should be avoided. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You can use `np.where` to convert boolean to index: `move[np.where((rf_current> rf_max).squeeze())] = np.nan`. The `squeeze` ensures a 1-D index is returned. BTW, in parts of your question you have `move` and in some other `moves`

Comment: You can't use broadcasting during indexing, but can simpy use `move[(rf_current > rf_max).squeeze(), :] = np.nan`